# 3rd Oder Homogeneous DE - stable/unstable equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Consider a 3rd order linear homogeneous DE of the form $$Lu=u'''+a_2(x)u''+a_1(x)u'+a_0(x)u=f(x) \ \ \ \ (1)$$
>   and for which $u_1=e^{-x}$ and $u_2=e^{-2x}$ are solutions to the homogeneous form of $(1)$.
>
> Let $f(x)=10e^{-2x}$. Give an example of a form of $a_2, a_1$ and $a_0$ such that $(1)$ has a stable equilibrium point and an example such that $(1)$ has no stable equilibrium point.

My attempt:

When I think of stability, I immediately think of eigenvalues (nodes etc). Hence I reduced $(1)$ into a system of linear equations:
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt}&=y, \\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=z, \\
\frac{dz}{dt}&=-a_2z-a_1y-a_0u. \\
\end{align}
This gives a corresponding matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    -a_0 & -a_1 & -a_2
\end{pmatrix}.$$
But after working with this, I feel as if I'm not on the right track. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In particular, $u_1$ and $u_2$ are homogeneous solutions:
\begin{aligned}
-1 + a_2 - a_1 + a_0 &= 0 \\
-8 + 4 a_2 - 2 a_1 + a_0 &= 0
\end{aligned}
i.e. $a_1 = 2 + \frac{3}{2} a_0$ and $a_2 = 3 + \frac{1}{2} a_0$.
Now, it remains to examine the stability of the equilibrium points, which are the constants $u^*$ such that $a_0 u^* = f$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $-2$, $-1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}a_0$. Therefore, if $a_0=\alpha u_2$ with $\alpha>0$, the system has a single stable equilibrium point $u^* = 10/\alpha$. However, if for instance $a_0 = \beta u_1$, the system has no equilibrium point.